# Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, jooq, jooq-sbt-plugin

Now I'm working with jooq library and I tried many times to solve the problem by searching here and there .

This is pom.xml

```
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.5</version>

  <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>jooq-codegen</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.1208</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <configuration>
    <jdbc>
      <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
      <url>jdbc:postgresql:jOOQ</url>
      <user>postgres</user>
      <password>root</password>
    </jdbc>

    <generator>
      <database>
        <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
        <includes>.*</includes>
        <excludes></excludes>
        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
      </database>
      <target>
        <packageName>org.thoughts.on.java.db</packageName>
        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
      </target>
    </generator>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After running this ->Maven build the results are like this :(hello is the name of my project)

```
[INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate (jooq-codegen) @ hello ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.024 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-25T13:01:11+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.5:generate (jooq-codegen) on project hello: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: La tentative de connexion a échoué. Séquence UTF-8 illégale: l'octet 2 de la séquence d'octet 3 n'est pas 10xxxxxx: 101 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

After clicking at Maven build I tried all of this in goals box: install / package / generate/ generate-sources but none of them works! anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you sure your JDBC connection URL is correct?

Comment: Yes the problem is with the goal : generate ??

Comment: My next guess is you should update your JDBC driver version. The current version is `42.2.5`. In any case, this is quite likely a JDBC problem, not really a jOOQ problem, given the error message you're getting.